# Rails Active Records SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: subs.subscriber_id: SELECT "subs".* FROM "subs" WHERE "subs"."subscriber_id" =?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, sqlite

I have Used `Has_many` relation to a `Subscriber` and `Sub models`

```
class Sub < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :Subscriber
end

class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subs

end
```

While inserting record to `Sub` table bu sung

I am getting the below error as follows

**Error Log**

```
Rails Console.
 a=Subscriber.find(1)
  Subscriber Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscribers".* FROM "subscribers" WHERE "subscribers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Subscriber id: 1, name: "arun", created_at: "2015-12-22 07:38:34", updated_at: "2015-12-22 07:38:34">
irb(main):002:0> a.subs
  Sub Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "subs".* FROM "subs" WHERE "subs"."subscriber_id" = ?  [[nil, 1]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: subs.subscriber_id: SELECT "subs".* FROM "subs" WHERE "subs"."subscriber_id" = ?
```

Comment: The error means the column is missing, which either means you still have to run migrations, or you have no migration for (or not added) a `subscriber_id` column in the first place.

Comment: Do you have subscriber_id in your subs table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
class Sub < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subscriber
end

class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :subs
end
```

make **SURE** you have run **migrations**. 
Dont use **CAPITAL** in **associations**.

Also can you share your schema ??

PS: Please indent your code.

Comment: create_table "subs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "contenr"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

Comment: Follow @vipin suggested above

Answer (score 0):

use this `belongs_to :subscriber`

**if not work than**

**Add subscriber_id column to subs**

or

**type following rails command**

```
rails g migration AddSubscriber_idToSub subscriber_id:integer
```

**then**

```
rake db:migrate
```